# Modifying XSLT changes library style, removes Search Box?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I modified the XSLT of a SharePoint 2013 library to set the width of a multiple lines of text column, following the advice [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/07512437-fecf-4257-bcc8-ba3c8e467554/how-to-increase-width-of-a-list-in-sharepoint-designer-2013/). The relevant code:

`<th nowrap="nowrap" scope="col" onmouseover="OnChildColumn(this)">`

to

`<th scope="col" onmouseover="OnChildColumn(this)" style ="width: 350px; white-space:normal;min-width:350px">`

For some reason, this changed the style of the library to no longer be "Default", which removes the search box at the top of the library. Keeping this search box is a key requirement, does anyone know how to force the search box to appear in non-"Default" styles, or a workaround that would keep the search box while still setting the width of the column?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish what I wanted to accomplish using JQuery. Did you know you have to use `<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">` in the actual payload script? I didn't! I also didn't know you have to enclose the jQuery in the HTML header. Also, when using jQuery with SharePoint, use "jQuery" instead of "$" in your code. I hope this helps another jQuery newbie like me.